# Getting number of rows of a query as output when COUNT(*) can't be used

Tags: sql, count, psql

I have this query that returns 13 rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT title,year FROM MovieAwards WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Movies WHERE MovieAwards.title = Movies.title AND Movies.year = MovieAwards.year AND Movies.year >= 2000 AND Movies.year <= 2010 AND MovieAwards.result='won');
```

Now i need to use the number of rows of this query as a float for other queries. I am aware that i can use THIS AND AS to store the number of rows in some temporary variable. But i can't find a single way to modify the first query to output 13.

If i do
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MovieAwards WHERE EXISTS IN (the code above)

i get a very different number as title,year is not the key of MovieAwards.

I also tried to replace title,year with count(title,year) but i'm guessing that isn't allowed.

I can't think of anything else to try.
Any help would be apretiated.

Edit:
Thanks @nbk for your code. Individually it works perfectly. However when I try to use it I get either a syntax error or a casting error. This last attempt below in particular gives a generic syntax error:

```
WITH
"won" AS
(SELECT COUNT(*)::FLOAT
  FROM MovieAwards 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Movies WHERE MovieAwards.title = Movies.title AND Movies.year = MovieAwards.year AND Movies.year >= 2000 AND Movies.year <= 2010 AND MovieAwards.result='won')
GROUP BY title,year),

"total" AS
(SELECT COUNT(*)::FLOAT
FROM Movies
WHERE Movies.year >=2000 AND Movies.year <=2010)

SELECT success-rate AS ( CASE WHEN (total = 0) THEN '-1' (ELSE won/total) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` title and year and count the result

```
SELECT COUNT(*)::FLOAT
  FROM MovieAwards 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Movies WHERE MovieAwards.title = Movies.title AND Movies.year = MovieAwards.year AND Movies.year >= 2000 AND Movies.year <= 2010 AND MovieAwards.result='won')
GROUP BY "title","year";
```

| count |
| --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yHbwad5D)

Comment: I tried using this and calling this query 'won' using a WITH and another like it 'total'. But when i try to use them to get what i want i keep getting syntax errors. I'm trying to do this : SELECT ( CASE WHEN SUM(won)=0 THEN -1 ELSE ( SUM(won)/SUM(total) ) ) AS col;   But i keep getting a generic syntax error. I also tried COUNT instead of SUM but it gives the same error.

Comment: give a fiddle with the hole code, i can't understand what you tried,

Comment: sorry I dont know how to use fiddle yet. I added my last attempt in an edit of the question.

Comment: use the link in my answer change it with your query, run the code and post the link again here in the comment

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/BX_CynZ5  i tried changing it a little bit and now it gives a syntax error instead of the casting errors.

Comment: You should really make a tutorial abot postgres an sql or at least read the manual you hadn many,many errors, that show that you haven't learn basic sql https://dbfiddle.uk/kfmAs24R

Comment: yeah you're right. I'm currently following a course on sql. Sorry if it was pretty stupid mistakes. Anyway thanks it works now! And i can see what i was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the count of some literal to get a count for your selection.
Please refer below.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT title,year FROM MovieAwards WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Movies WHERE MovieAwards.title = Movies.title AND Movies.year = MovieAwards.year AND Movies.year >= 2000 AND Movies.year <= 2010 AND MovieAwards.result='won'));
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But if i try to put it under a THIS and call it say 'won' when i try to use it as a float i get a cannot cast type record to double precision error. what can i do to fix that?

Comment: @MatteoSpinelli If this answered your current question, you can mark my answer as answered and give an upvote for encouraging further clarify your doubts.